# Is the use of conditional type correct?

Tags: conditional-constructions

I'm confused with the use of conditional type in the following sentences:

> In the olden days, the life of a soldier had such a hard duty and exhaustion. If so, today in the Union army, how hard and exhausted the life of a soldier would be.

Please explain it to me.

Comment: Which "Union army" are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

The sentences you quote are borderline ungrammatical. What is the source of the example sentences?

If I understand correctly, the phrase "how hard and exhausted the life of a soldier" uses the word '[how' as an intensifier (sense 7)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/how). 'If so' generally means 'if the the preceding statement is true'.

Putting it together, the meaning is: "Taking into account that the life of olden day soldiers was hard, the life of soldiers today is much harder".

However the sentences are odd. Are they from a native speaker? Is there some wider context?

Comment: I don't think there is anything borderline about it. At least to me there isn't anyway.